# A new view page ( .cshtml ) in the .net framework mvc4

Tags: razor

What is the use of .cshtml page in .net mvc4 ?

I am very new to MVC 4. Can any one please tell me about the use of .cshtml view page.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423732/razor-cshtml-any-benefit-over-what-we-have

Answer (score 0):

Then you should visit http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started and read through the basics.

Everything will get explained

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unspecific.

Please edit your question to answer the following:

- What do you want do achieve?
- Do you have problems understanding the MVC pattern?
- Do you wonder what the difference between html and cshtml is?

In general the view page is used to display a model, but if you didn't know this you should start reading about the Model View Controller pattern. (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller but you find thousands of good links)