# Html to cshtml online converter

Tags: html

I am new to asp.net I need to convert html code to cshtml.I am looking for online converter Can anybody help me?
Is there any online converter to convert html code to cshtml?

Answer (score 0):

cshtml is also a html, In which you can write your asp code and logic.

currently **no such tool present** which gives you cshtml pages, you need to do it manually, and its way more easier.
In cshtml you got advante to reuse and seperate your html code into multiple modules.

for more advantages you can see: [cshtml benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423732/razor-cshtml-any-benefit-over-what-we-have)

[Some cshtml code containing razor syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nZNH.png)

Comment: ok .But its showing error `Server Error in '/' Application.` can you please help me.I just added one `div` part in view page.why its showing error?please help me

Comment: you are getting server error, because of config. Could you check the App_Start/RouteConfig.cs,

**
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "hom", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
**
where controller will be your default controller and action will be your default method in controller.